# How can I center vertically a bootstrap class button?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to get a button inside a `form-actions` vertically:

This is how is displayed:

[image]

So that green button is being displayed down to its div (the blue area). How can I get to center it. I use a `style.css` file where I've styled some other divs.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Is this what you need! Here is a demo, please check and let me know if you need anything else.

http://jsfiddle.net/fkQBf/

```
<div style="height: 200px; border: solid 2px green; text-align:center;line-height:200px;">
    <input type="submit" Value="Ok" style="vertical-align: middle"></input>
</div>
```

**Updated code and fiddle:**

We should not use inline styles, so below is the updated fiddle with separate style

http://jsfiddle.net/fkQBf/1/

```
<div id="container">
    <input id="verticalButton" type="submit" Value="Ok"></input>
</div>

div#container
{
    height: 200px; 
    border: solid 2px green; text-align:center;
    line-height:200px;
}

input#verticalButton
{
     vertical-align: middle
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Did you got a typo or actually I should do `div#container` and `input#verticalButton`?

Comment: It is not typo, if can also use only #container. But div#container selector selects the element having container and of type div.

Comment: Check this http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_id_class.asp for better understanding

Answer (score 6):

Since I didn't want to set an absolute height, I used flex boxes.

```css
/* Latest compiled and minified CSS included as External Resource*/

/* Optional theme */
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');

body {
    margin: 10px;
}

.container {
  height:50%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center; /* vertically aligned! */
  justify-content: center;
}

.other {
  height:320px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="other"><!-- Other content -->
Welcome to my great site!
  <div class="container"> <!-- the container you want that button -->
      <button class="btn btn-danger btn-lg">
      Hello World
      </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a great answer

Answer (score 1):

use some style like

```
display:table-cell; //main div

vertical-align:center; // to button
```

If this will not worked than try

```
height:100%; // to button
vertical-align:center; // to button
line-height : 100%;  // to button
```

Comment: What should I do to style the button, `.button` or `#button`?

Comment: If you define class to the button than use .classname
or you define id for button than use #idname
you can use any one of these.

Comment: Just to confirm any property is modified/appended to the class or id, right?

Comment: The first solution does not work. The second solution stretches the button full height.

Comment: vertical-align:center ? that doesn't exist, it is vertical-align:middle